# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings' on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: mediapipe

I'm having problems using mediapipe on my raspberry pi 3.
Using "import mediapipe" gives no error, however using "mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils" (for example) gives out the following error message:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings'**

My installation method was:

**sudo apt install ffmpeg python3-opencv python3-pip ;**

**sudo apt install libxcb-shm0 libcdio-paranoia-dev libsdl2-2.0-0 libxv1 libtheora0 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2 libvdpau1 libharfbuzz0b libbluray2 libatlas-base-dev libhdf5-103 libgtk-3-0 libdc1394-22 libopenexr25 ;**

**sudo pip3 uninstall mediapipe-rpi3 .**

I'm using a raspberry pi 3b with debian bullseye (32 bit), my python version is 3.9.2 and the opencv version is 4.2.1.
P.S. the file name is "maos.py".

Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

(I annexed an image of the error aswell for clarity)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryyQr.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

For me, it wasn't installed properly. SO I USED THIS COMMAND -

```
pip install mediapipe --user
```

and made sure I had latest python version installed on my pc. And it worked.

Earlier I was making a mistake of writing -

```
pip install mediapipe
```

Comment: `pip install mediapipe` worked for me and not `pip install mediapipe --user` as I am installing in python virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Finally I found mediapipe does not work on raspbian **bullseye** it works with raspbian **buster**. Try to change it if you are using bullseye. Also check this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vF6fwKN06lM